# Webscraping data from a json source

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, request

So, I'am trying to get some information from a website with python, from a webshop.

[image: This is the json code]

I tried this one:

```
my_url = requests.get(MY_URL)

data = my_url.json()

name = data['MainContent'][0]['contents'][0]['productList']['products'][0]['productModel']["displayName"]
price = data['MainContent'][0]['contents'][0]['productList']['products'][0]['priceInfo']['priceItemSale']["gross"]
url= data['MainContent'][0]['contents'][0]['productList']['products'][0]['productModel']["url"]
        
filename = "test.csv"
csv_writer = csv.writer(open(filename, 'w'))
headers = "Name, Price, Link\n"
f.write(headers)
f.close()
```

In this webshop there are a lot of product with these attribute "productModel", but how can i get these all and write into a csv?
I want web-scraping the name, the price and the url link this page in differents cells.

Comment: can you provide the url? Also, post valid json as code where possible between code tags.

Comment: You mean "scraping"?  Because "scrapping" sounds like you want to throw it away.

Comment: No screenshots please.  Just post the code into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
for mc in data['MainContent']:
    for co in mc:
        for prod in co['productList']['products']:
            name = prod['productModel']['displayName']
```